# How to configure Tesults report with CodeceptJS

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, codeceptjs

I am trying to integrate Tesults dashboard with CodeceptJS + Playwright tests, but there seems not to be a way to pass playwright report configuration through codeceptJs' conf file.

Documentation specifies that for playwright use `reporter: [['playwright-tesults-reporter', {'tesults-target': 'token'}]]` but that is inside the **Playwright.config.js** file which doesn't exist in codeceptJS projects.

Is there a way to pass such configuration through codeceptJs' conf file?

Tesults documentation https://www.tesults.com

Answer (score 1):

Tesults just developed a specific CodeceptJS integration now!!

Comment: Link to integration: https://www.tesults.com/docs/codeceptjs